# How can I manage the lifetime of my PHP sessions?

Tags: php, session, cookies, lifetime, cache-expiration

I am quite new to PHP, so I'm working on a simple project to practise. However, I can't manage to make the session management work properly.

What I want is that when the browser is closed, the data (the current page the user is at) is saved for an hour. If the user returns within an hour, he should see the same page he left, and if he return after an hour, he should see the first question.

When all questions have been answered, he should see a score-screen, with a "Try Again" button that preferably destroys/kills/deletes the session and starts a new one, directing the user to the first question.

If I leave out line 3-8 my code works as expected, I run throught the questions until I get stuck at the score-screen with a non-working "Try Again" button, I can only go back to the first question by closing and reopening the browser.

With these lines, the page runs through the questions fine but when I restart the browser, it starts at the first question. When I close the browser without doing anything and open the page a second time, I find the page I left at first. I close and open the browser again and I find the correct page again, I do it again and I'm back to question 0. No matter how often I then restart the browser, I stay at question 0.

When I look at the cookies in my browser, I have the same cookie all the time, one that started at 14 december 2015 18:48:45. However, the experation time isn't correct either, as that is 26 november 2061 13:37:29, instead of an hour later. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
/* Sart (new) session*/
if (isset($_GET['TryAgain'])){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION = array();
    session_destroy();
}
session_set_cookie_params(time()+3600);
session_start();
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/* IMPORT DATABASE: $qs[i]=question text, $as[i]=array(choices per question),
$as[i][i]=array('t'=>choice text, 'c'=>BOOLEAN) */
require_once('config.php');
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db;host=$host", $user, $password);
$questions = $dbh->prepare('select * from questions');
$questions->execute();
$choices = $dbh->prepare('select * from choices');
$choices->execute();
$qs = array();
$as = array();

foreach($questions as $row) {
    $i = $row['q_nr'];
    $qs[$i] = $row['q_text'];
}

foreach($choices as $row) {
    $qi = $row['q_nr'];
    $ci = $row['c_nr'];
    $as[$qi][$ci] = array('t'=>$row['c_text'],'c'=>$row['correct']);
}
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*INITIALIZE SESSION VARIABLES*/

/* Creates counter-variable if not set -------- (ini value is 0)*/
if(!isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = 0;
}

/* Creates score-variable if not set -------- (ini value is 0)*/
if(!isset($_SESSION['score'])) {
    $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
}
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* SET COUNTER, SCORE AND DONE*/

/* Check if answer previous question has been submitted*/
if (isset($_GET['a'])) {
    $submitted = true;
} else {
    $submitted = false;
}

/* Set counter*/
if ($submitted){
    $_SESSION['counter'] += 1;
}
$cqi = $_SESSION['counter'];

/* Set score*/
if ($submitted) {
    if ($as[$cqi-1][$_GET['a']]['c']){
        $_SESSION['score'] += 1;
    }
} 
$score = $_SESSION['score'];

/* Check done*/
if($cqi >= count($qs)){
    $done = true;
} else {
    $done = false;
}

echo 'cqi: '.$cqi;
echo 'done: '.$done;
/*-------------------------------------------------------------------*/
?>

<!-- START HTML!!! -->

<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
    <br><br>
    <?php 
        if($done){
            echo 'You finished the quiz. <br> Your score is: '.$score;
            echo "<form action='index.php' method='get'>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='TryAgain' value=true>";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Try again!'>";
            echo "</form>";
        } else {
            echo $qs[$cqi];
            echo "<form action='index.php' method='get'>";
            $cci = 0;
            foreach($as[$cqi] as $cc){
                echo "<input type='radio' name='a' value=".$cci.">".
                $cc['t']."<br>";
                $cci++;
                }
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Next question'>";
            echo "</form>";
            echo "<br><br>Current score: ".$score;
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me, I really am stuck with this.

-Edit-

I tried again omitting line 3-8 and keeping `session_set_cookie_params(600);`, to test this function as simply as possible. I tested it the same way as cited above, reopening my browser time and time again and noting down which question I got (q. 0 or 1). I got a seemingly random pattern, of first question 0 and the question I should be on, 1, in which 0 is often the most prevalent. I am quite sure it is random, as I removed the cookie and redid the test multiple times and each time I saw a different pattern. The cookie *does* expire now at the right time though.

I also tried the `ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 600);` instead of `session_set_cookie_params(600);` function, as suggested in the other question, but I still had random results. And I don't think it is a good idea for me to try and create a login system if I even can't get this right...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to restore old session when user accidentally closes the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157928/how-to-restore-old-session-when-user-accidentally-closes-the-browser)